# Building nested arrays in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

So I'm trying to build a JSON object with an array nested inside the main users array.

I'm having a bit of trouble building the data model in the PHP. Can anyone give any pointers?

Desired output:

```
[{
            id: 2,
            name: "John Wilson",
            profilePic: "fighter-1.jpg",
            activities: [{
                id: 6431,
                time: (57).minutes().ago(),
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 20
            }]
        }, {
            id: 3,
            name: "Christoper Robin",
            profilePic: "fighter-3.jpg",
            activities: [{
                id: 6431,
                time: (1).days().ago,
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                time: (2).days().ago,
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 20
            }]
        }, {
            id: 1,
            name: "Jerry Seinfeld",
            profilePic: "placeholder.jpg",
            activities: [{
                id: 6431,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6431,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 20
            }, {
                id: 6432,
                time: new Date(),
                points: 100
            }]
        }]
```

The PHP and MySQL:

```
$getCompUsers = mysql_query("SELECT c.userid, u.name, u.profilePic, a.activity_typeid, a.userid, a.time, a.activity_weight, a.activityname
        FROM competitionmembers c 
        INNER JOIN users1 u ON  u.id = c.userid 
        INNER JOIN activity_entries a ON a.userid = u.id
        WHERE c.competitionid = '$competitionId'") or die("Couldn't select competitions users");

$compUsersArr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getCompUsers,MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$compUsersArr = array(
            'id' => $row["userid"],
            'name'=> $row["name"],
            'profilePic' => $row["profilePic"], 
                $activities = array( //THIS SEEMS TO BE THE PROBLEM
                    'id' => $row["activity_typeid"],
                    'name' => $row["activityname"],
                    'points' => $row["activity_weight"]
                    )
            );
    }
```

Comment: Some pointers for you: [0x3A28213A 0x6339392C, 0x7363682E](http://xkcd.com/138/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are making your array is wrong, to nest [**`arrays`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php) you don't have to use variables in array as you did

```
$compUsersArr = array(
        'id' => $row["userid"],
        'name'=> $row["name"],
        'profilePic' => $row["profilePic"], 
        'activities' => array(
            'id' => $row["activity_typeid"],
            'name' => $row["activityname"],
            'points' => $row["activity_weight"]
        )
);
```

Comment: other than the small typo = should be => when building the 2nd array, that's great. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your code was almost correct; splitting it up will make you see why it didn't:

```
$activities = array(
    'id' => $row["activity_typeid"],
    'name' => $row["activityname"],
    'points' => $row["activity_weight"]
);

$compUsersArr = array(
    'id' => $row["userid"],
    'name'=> $row["name"],
    'profilePic' => $row["profilePic"], 
    $activities,
);
```

This will create an array like:

```
[
    'id' => 123, 
    'name' => 'foo', 
    'profilePic' => 'bar', 
    0 => ['id' => 456, 'name' => 'baz', 'points' => 'quz']
]
```

You would probably want this:

```
$compUsersArr = array(
    'id' => $row["userid"],
    'name'=> $row["name"],
    'profilePic' => $row["profilePic"], 
    'activities' => $activities,
);
```